# Node JS emit socket after error in SQL query

Tags: sql, node.js, socket.io

**Hello, please do you know how can I send message to client via socket when I have error in my SQl query on server side ? **

Server side

```
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected: " + socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnet', () => {
        console.log("disconnected");
    })

.post('/addDiel', (req, res) => {   //Pridanie dielu do DB
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err 
        console.log(`Pripojene ako ID ${connection.threadId}`)

        const params = req.body;
        

        res.send({
            MenoDielures: params.MenoDielu, 
            DruhDielures: params.DruhDielu,
            ProjektNameres: params.ProjektName
        }) 

        ProjektNameDB = params.ProjektName.split('.').join("_");

            connection.query('INSERT INTO `Skener_db`.`?` (`MenoDielu`, `DruhDielu`, `DatumCas`) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())', [ProjektNameDB, params.MenoDielu, params.DruhDielu],(err, rows)=> {
            connection.release()

    
            if(!err) {
                res.send(console.log(`Hodnota ${params.MenoDielu} bola pridana.`))
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                if (err.code == ('ER_DUP_ENTRY')) {
                    //send message to client
                }
                //res.send({alertMessage: 'Diel už bol oskenovaný. Oskenuj ďaľší.'})
            }
        })
        console.log(req.body)  
    })     
})
})
```

My client side:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
      $('#skuska').html("Socket pripojeny");
})
    socket.on('receiveDUPmessage', message => {
     $('#skuska').html(message);
})
```

The code here is just for example. I didnt find solution for my problem, so I'm asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to emit events and socket is locally scoped. `io.sockets` is not, So you can do it like this on the server-side:

```
if(!err) {
   res.send(console.log(`Hodnota ${params.MenoDielu} bola pridana.`))
} else {
   console.log(err);
   if (err.code == ('ER_DUP_ENTRY')) {
       //send message to client
       io.sockets.emit('my error', 'Some error happened');
   }
   //res.send({alertMessage: 'Diel už bol oskenovaný. Oskenuj ďaľší.'})
}
```

And on the client-side do this:

```
socket.on('my error', function (text) {
   console.log(text);
});
```

Here is some sort of posts that may help you:

[How to emit error to be possible catch it on error handler on client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872052/how-to-emit-error-to-be-possible-catch-it-on-error-handler-on-client-side)

[How to emit a socket.io response within post request in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776387/how-to-emit-a-socket-io-response-within-post-request-in-nodejs)

Comment: Wooow, thank you so so much. Its working. Im sitting in front of it 3 days and it's finally working. Thanks man really.